# Why is this code not rendering the content I'm specifying?

Tags: hugo

For this Hugo site, I have two sections in my "content" folder, "posts" and "projects", each with their own pages. The `site.com/projects/` and `site.com/posts/` pages display their relevant content correctly. On my home page, I'd like to display some entries of both sections. Here is `layouts/index.html`:

```
{{ define "main" }}

    <div class="homepage-content">
        {{ .Content }}
    </div>

    <h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
    <div class="articles">
        {{ $post_pages := where (where site.Pages "Type" "in" "posts") "Params.hidden" "!=" true }}
        {{ range (.Paginate $post_pages).Pages }}
            {{ partial "post-summary.html" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>

    <h1>Projects:</h1>
    <div class="articles">
        {{ $project_pages := where (where site.Pages "Type" "in" "projects") "Params.hidden" "!=" true }}
        {{ range (.Paginate $project_pages).Pages }}
            {{ partial "post-summary.html" . }}
        {{ end }}
    </div>

    {{ partial "pagination.html" . }}

{{ end }}
```

What happens is, that both code blocks end up rendering a list of the pages from the "posts" section, and if I reverse the order (placing the code block for the "projects" section first) they both display pages from the "projects" section. What seems to be happening is that there's some kind of hidden variable that isn't being reset between the code blocks. After going through the Hugo docs for about an hour, I couldn't for the life of me find the reason. I've already specified both sections under "mainSections" in the params file if that makes any difference (although I don't imagine it does)

For reference, I'm using the [anubis](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/hugo-theme-anubis/) theme as a base (although it's been somewhat heavily modified) but again, I don't think it's related.

Comment: What if you replace Type with Section in your where and leave out the 'in'...?

Comment: @Mr.Hugo I tried that, unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: And site.Pages with .Site.RegularPages?

Comment: @Mr.Hugo That was actually the initial configuration, I changed it to this when trying to make it work. I tried RegularPages again now just in case and nope, still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kind member of the Hugo forum has answered my question:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/list-is-displaying-content-from-the-wrong-section/41255

I made two mistakes. I [paginated](https://gohugo.io/templates/pagination/) twice, which doesn't work. I also used `.Pages` instead of `.RegularPages`, which isn't recommended (see [here](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/#pages)).

User `jmooring` provided the following two options for how I could do what I was attempting:

- "If you want to paginate, build a sorted collection of both posts and projects, then paginate the collection. See [https://gohugo.io/functions/union/"](https://gohugo.io/functions/union/%22)
- "Display the first N posts under the Posts heading (with a link to more), and display the first N projects under the Projects heading (with a link to more). See [https://gohugo.io/functions/first/"](https://gohugo.io/functions/first/%22)

Comment: Hi Hayden, links to external sources tend to go down all the time even though your answer may be looked at in years from now. I'd really appreciate it if you could paraphrase the solution in your answer alongside a link to the original post.

Comment: @Mike Very good point. I went ahead and did so, please let me know if I should improve my answer further in any way.